# Unable to SSH into Vagrant guest

Tags: ssh, vagrant

Until recently I was able to SSH into my Vagrant machine without any problems. Now however:

`$ ssh -vvv vagrant@127.0.0.1 -p 2222
OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.1, OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug2: resolving "127.0.0.1" port 2222
debug2: ssh_connect_direct: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to 127.0.0.1 [127.0.0.1] port 2222.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/user1/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/user1/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/user1/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/user1/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/user1/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/user1/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/user1/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/user1/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.1
ssh_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer`

I checked `/etc/hosts.allow` and `/etc/hosts.deny` in the guest. Nothing there. I'm almost sure this has something to do with someone rewriting the contents of `/etc/resolv.conf`. The contents are now:

`nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4`

The network seems to be fine on the host where I can ping google.com, but not on the guest, where I can't. But SSH to the Vagrant machine is no longer working. Any ideas?

Comment: What errors do  you see in the server log?

Comment: I'm not sure I'm looking at the right one. I did `tail -f /var/log/audit/audit.log` and `tail-f /var/log/secure` but saw nothing when I tried to SSH into the machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is not at all what I expected. In VirtualBox Settings > Network > Adapter 1 the Cable Connected option was disabled. After enabling it everything went back to normal.